# Ruby on Rails / Devise - Bypassing custom validation option in model when resetting password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

In my project, I altered the registration form in Devise to add an :agree option via an accessor (user must accept terms of service to register, etc). If they don't agree, it doesn't validate.

That caused a problem when a user tried to edit their account information as it seeked out the :agree validation, but I was able to add an 'unless' clause and added another accessor called :signed_in that is defined in the controller (I couldn't figure out how to get the model to determine if the user was signed in or not, devise's helpers wouldn't work for me in it). The relevant portions of my User model and users_controller look like...

user.rb

```
validates :agree, :term_agreement => TRUE, :unless => :signed_in
```

users_controller.rb

```
def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])

   if user_signed_in?
     @user.signed_in = params[:user]
   end

  [...]
end
```

So, it all works fine...the "agree" validation overrides when a user is already signed in. However, I have to figure out the best way to override another scenario...when a user resets their password and needs to change it.

I was testing user accounts and tried to reset my password on one account, however I was hit with the :agree validation...now I have to figure out a way to override that. I noticed the Change your password form has a hidden field value of :reset_password_token, however I tried :unless => :reset_password_token but it wouldn't work.

So what is the best way of accomplishing this? On top of that, how can I have an either / or condition (unless :signed_in or :reset_password, etc) for that :unless clause?

Comment: Or to flip the question completely around (as this may be the better and more efficient route as I think about it), is there a way to only validate for :agree if this is a new user registration and not on any other action (update user, password reset, etc)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, you need to validate the acceptance of terms when the record is created?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :agree, :acceptance => true, :on => :create
end
```

`:on => :create` will only perform that validation when the record is being created—much like Brandon's answer, but without redundant code.

This will also obviate the need for your controllers to worry about if a user is signed in or not.

Comment: Completely forgot about the `:on` option, perfect tool for the job.

Comment: This answer is great for several reasons, obviously one for that it works, but also that I did not know you could validate :on actions. In addition, it cleans up/refactors much of my code as I can drop the controller stuff, as well as the custom validator I used (completely forgot about it). Thank you much.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to base these kinds of things on whether or not the record is new (which is the only time the user will be "signing up").

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :agree, :term_agreement => TRUE, :if => :signing_up?

  # Return true if the user is currently signing up
  def signing_up?
    new_record?
  end
end
```

The key is to keep in mind that the value of `:if` and `:unless` is "a method, proc or string to call to determine if the validation should [or should not] occur"--so you're free to define methods on your model for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by configuring devise to update the password attributes directing if validation failed, but only if the password attributes are error free.

See my answer here:

[Validation errors are triggered when I'm trying to reset password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849427/validation-errors-are-triggered-when-im-trying-to-reset-password/33807451#33807451)