# Devise, requiring user to accept terms of service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I want to mandate that all users accept terms of service, much like is described here:

[Ruby on Rails / Devise - Bypassing custom validation option in model when resetting password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762009/ruby-on-rails-devise-bypassing-custom-validation-option-in-model-when-resett)

However there are 2 requirements that make the above approach not fit.

1) Users are not self registered, rather they are created by a system administrator. The administrator obviously can't accept terms and conditions on the users behalf. The user should be prompted to accept terms and conditions on their first login.

2) If the terms and conditions change after the fact. Users need to re-accept the new terms on subsequent logins.

These seem like pretty standard workflows. Does devise provide any way to accomplish this?

If not, I am thinking this check will need to be implemented in a before_filter on my application controller. (Feels dirty mixing authentication with the application logic...)

Will I have to resort to this or can anyone suggest a better way?

Thanks

Comment: I think devise / auth has nothing to do with business logic (terms). You'll have to do a before filter in application controller. You're not mixing auth with business logic. The user is authenticated but it cannot access any page until it will accept the terms of use

Answer (score 3):

this is not something devise would handle and devise should not handle this because a TOS does not pertain to authentication.

What you could do is something like implement a state machine but that may be more complex than what you need.

The simple way would be to add a accepted_tos boolean field to your user model and tie that into a before_filter then you would set the accepted_tos to false everytime the TOS is updated.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you theoretically just disable moving further in your app using JQuery?

Disable your form "continue" or "log in" button until they have checked a box or hit a continue button, then enable your log in button once they have.

If you need to store that information just make a column in your database on the user which gets posted too when they check the box or hit the continue button, or you could even utilize the number of log in counts as a way of knowing.

If user.logs > 0 then the user has already accepted the terms.
If user.logs == 0 then the user needs to accept the terms before they log in.

I guess according to your question it seems like tying everything into Devise sounds overly complex.

Hope this helps.